# How to distribute a windows application that uses windows runtime in an installer?

Tags: windows, windows-runtime

I have a windows application that uses windows runtime and trying to install it dependencies on another windows machine. The linker is using WindowsApp.lib but I can't find a DLL with that library.

Comment: You shouldn't have to distribute anything, but you'll need to check if the APIs you use are available https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2015/09/15/dynamically-detecting-features-with-api-contracts-10-by-10/. What problem do you have exactly when you try to execute the compiled application?

Comment: Thanks! I had another problem that was easier to find after your comment.